# How does newly introduced Arrays.parallelPrefix(...) in Java 8 work?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

I came across [Arrays.parallelPrefix](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelPrefix-double:A-java.util.function.DoubleBinaryOperator-) introduced in Java 8.

This overloaded method performs operation on each element of the input array in a cumulative fashion. For e.g. from docs:

> Cumulates, in parallel, each element of the given array in place,
>   using the supplied function. For example if the array initially holds
>   [2, 1, 0, 3] and the operation performs addition, then upon return the
>   array holds [2, 3, 3, 6]. Parallel prefix computation is usually more
>   efficient than sequential loops for large arrays.

So, how does Java achieve this task in `parallel` when the operation on a term is dependent on the operation result on the previous term, and so on?

I tried going through the code myself and they do use `ForkJoinTasks`, but it's not so straightforward how they would merge result to get the final array.

Comment: Nice question. +1 .. *Parallel prefix computation is usually more efficient than sequential loops for large arrays* ... every day there is a lot more for me here to learn and I love it.

Comment: FWIW, the source code (with fairly extensive comments) is [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/d682023cdd8c/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l1580) and [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/d682023cdd8c/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayPrefixHelpers.java).

Comment: If you want to read more about how *tremendously powerful* this sort of operation can be, I'd highly recommend the PhD thesis (or papers) by Guy Blelloch : https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/papers/Ble90.pdf . I think the importance of his work - considering modern multi- and many-core hardware - is highly underrated.

Comment: Also , see this Dr Dobbs article:  http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/the-mystery-and-magic-of-prefix-scan/240001744

Comment: @DacidSoroko  Dr. Dobbs article is a gem. It explains how the prefix scan with _parallelism_ ends up doing much more operations than the _iteration logic_ but the **span** of the parallel algorithm is much lower(_O(log N)_ with unlimited processers).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As explained in [Eran’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52962054/2711488), this operation utilizes the associativity property of the function.

Then, there are two fundamental steps. The first one, is an actual prefix operation (in the sense of requiring the previous element(s) for the evaluation), applied to parts of the array in parallel. The result of each partial operation (identical to the resulting last element), is the offset for the remaining array.

E.g. for the following array, using sum as prefix operation, and four processors

```
  4    9    5    1    0    5    1    6    6    4    6    5    1    6    9    3
```

we get

```
  4 → 13 → 18 → 19    0 →  5 →  6 → 12    6 → 10 → 16 → 21    1 →  7 → 16 → 19  
                 ↓                   ↓                   ↓                   ↓  
                19                  12                  21                  19
```

now, we utilize the associativity to apply the prefix operation to the offsets first

```
                 ↓                   ↓                   ↓                   ↓  
                19         →        31         →        52         →        71
```

Then, we get to the second phase, which is to apply these offsets to each element of the next chunk, which is a perfectly parallelizable operation, as there is no dependency to the previous element(s) anymore

```
                     19   19   19   19   31   31   31   31   52   52   52   52  
                      ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓  
  4   13   18   19   19   24   25   31   37   41   47   52   53   59   68   71
```

When we use the same example for eight threads,

```
  4    9    5    1    0    5    1    6    6    4    6    5    1    6    9    3  

  4 → 13    5 →  6    0 →  5    1 →  7    6 → 10    6 → 11    1 →  7    9 → 12  
       ↓         ↓         ↓         ↓         ↓         ↓         ↓         ↓  
      13         6         5         7        10        11         7        12  

       ↓         ↓         ↓         ↓         ↓         ↓         ↓         ↓  
      13    →   19    →   24    →   31    →   41    →   52    →   59    →   71  

           13   13   19   19   24   24   31   31   41   41   52   52   59   59  
            ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓  
  4   13   18   19   19   24   25   31   37   41   47   52   53   59   68   71
```

we see that there will be a clear benefit, even when we use the simpler strategy of keeping the work chunks the same for both steps, in other words, accept one idle worker thread in the second phase. We will need about ⅛n for the first phase and ⅛n for the second, needing ¼n total for the operation (where *n* is the cost of the sequential prefix evaluation of the entire array). Of course, only roughly and in the best case.

In contrast, when we have only two processors

```
  4    9    5    1    0    5    1    6    6    4    6    5    1    6    9    3  


  4 → 13 → 18 → 19 → 19 → 24 → 25 → 31    6 → 10 → 16 → 21 → 22 → 28 → 37 → 40  
                                     ↓                                       ↓  
                                    31                                      40  

                                     ↓                                       ↓  
                                    31                   →                  71  

                                         31   31   31   31   31   31   31   31  
                                          ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓  
  4   13   18   19   19   24   25   31   37   41   47   52   53   59   68   71
```

we can only gain a benefit, when we re-assign the work of the second phase. This is possible, as said, because the second phase’s work has no dependencies between the elements anymore. So we can split this operation arbitrarily, though it complicates the implementation and may introduce an additional overhead.

When we split the work of the second phase between both processors, the first phase needs about ½n and the second will need ¼n, yielding ¾n total, which still is a benefit, if the array is large enough.

As an additional note, you might notice that the offsets calculated in preparation of the second phase are identical to the result for the last element of the chunk. So, you could reduce the required number of operations by one per chunk by simply assigning that value. But the typical scenario is to have only a few chunks (scaling with the number of processors) with a large number of elements, so saving one operation per chunk is not relevant.

Comment: @Holger I tried to look at the implementation, but this is out of my league way too much; but I was thinking why can't this be done in such a way that (second phase I mean), all the other results depend only on the first one - I mean, once the first one is know, all others can be done separately and independently. My answer should have been really a comment, but it would be way too long

Comment: 2 core example is crystal clear. Instead of taking `O(n)` time, this will be done in reduced time. We perform operations on the 2 halves in `O(n/2)` time parallelly. After this, we update the 2nd half with the sum from first half. This action can be done by splitting and submting the two halves of 2nd part to 2 cores. This operation will take `O(n/4)` parallelly. So, total time will be `O(n/2) + O(n/4) = O(3n/4)` which is `3/4th` of the time taken in the sequential way.

Comment: @AdityaGupta yes, but don’t use `O(…)` for notating this. The [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) has a specific meaning, in which the parallel execution still is `O(n)`, because it still scales linearly.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.

Comment: I guess, [span](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse332/17wi/lectures/forkjoin-2/Z-inked-b.pdf) should be the right term here.[other link](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15210-f15/www/tapp.html#_cost_model_work_and_span)

Answer (score 31):

The main point is that the operator is a

> side-effect-free, **associative** function

This means that

```
(a op b) op c == a op (b op c)
```

Therefore, if you split the array into two halves and apply the `parallelPrefix` method recursively on each half, you can later merge the partial results by applying the operation on each element of the second half of the array with the last element of the first half.

Consider the `[2, 1, 0, 3]` with addition example. If you split the array into two halves and perform the operation on each half, you get:

```
[2, 3]    and    [0, 3]
```

Then, in order to merge them, you add 3 (the last element of the first half) to each element of the second half, and get:

```
[2, 3, 3, 6]
```

EDIT: This answer suggests one way of computing the prefixes of an array in parallel. It's not necessarily the most efficient way, and not necessarily the way used by the JDK implementation. You can further read about parallel algorithms for solving that problem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum#Parallel_algorithm).

Comment: Ok, but, depending on what the function does, it is then essentially called multiple times on the elements of the second half. What is the point of parallelizing then, if the work must be made again?

Comment: @glglgl the merge work on the elements of the second half of the array can also be performed in parallel.

Comment: No matter in how may parts you split the array, the merge work is essentially the same as processing a "right" part. So for them, it doubles the work. I. e., each component of any "right" part must be touched twice. That's what concerns me.

Comment: @glglgl The benefit is that some operations can be done in parallel.  You might end up doing more work in total, but this can still be faster if the alternative is to have processing cores ideling.

Comment: _Associative_ ness makes sense. But, I have to agree with @glglgl here. It looks like the operations on the 2nd half are increased. Lets say, my operator was `addition`. 2nd half elements will face addition twice. Or, if we keep splitting the array till single element arrays, we don't really get the desired paralellism, since we will be performing `addition` at the merge stage.

Comment: @glglgl Let's count. Let `T` be the time take for `parallelPrefix`, then to compute the `parallelPrefix` of `n` elements you need `T(n/2)` time (because the two recursive calls are done in parallel!) plus `n/4` time for the merge phase (you can split the second half in two and do the two parts in parallel again, so `(n/2)/2`). For a total of `T(n) = T(n/2)+n/4`. This is  <`n`.

Comment: @AdityaGupta when you split down to single element arrays, the merge stage could be replaced with a simple assignment. However, in practice, the implementation won’t split that much down. I have added an answer demonstrating the operation and its savings by example.

Answer (score 2):

I read both the answers and still could not understand completely how this is done, so decided to draw an example instead. Here is what I came up with, suppose this is the array that we start with (with 3 CPU's):

```
7, 9, 6, 1, 8, 7, 3, 4, 9
```

So each of the 3 threads will get it's chunk to work on:

```
Thread 1:  7, 9, 6
Thread 2:  1, 8, 7
Thread 3:  3, 4, 9
```

Since the documentation mandates an *associative* function, we can compute the sum in the first Thread and some partial sums in the other ones, and when the first is known - all of them will. Let's see what `7, 9, 6` would become:

```
7, 9, 6  -> 7, 16, 22
```

So the sum in the first Thread is `22` - but other threads have no idea about that yet, so what they do instead is work against that as an `x` for example. Thus Thread 2, will be :

```
1, 8, 7 -> 1 (+x), 9 (+x), 16(+x)
```

Thus the sum from the second Thread would be `x + 16`, thus in `Thread 3`, we would have:

```
3, 4, 9 -> 3 (+ x + 16), 7 (+ x + 16), 16 (+ x + 16)

3, 4, 9 -> x + 19, x + 23, x + 32
```

This way, as soon as I know `x`, I know all other results too.

Disclaimer: I am not sure this is how it is implemented (and I tried looking at the code - but it's too complicated).

Comment: Nitpick: The 3rd thread would not know that the sum is `x + 16` since 16 comes by summing the elements in the 2nd block. It will only know that the sum is `x + y` where `x` is the sum of elements in the first block and `y` is the sum of elements in the 2nd block.

Comment: @LakshayGarg that is not nitpick, at all, I hoped someone will make this comment. But it seems that the same explanation in the other answers too, btw

Comment: Please, read my answer again, it explains this precisely. After the first step, you need to add `x` to the elements of the second chunk and need to add `x+y` to the elements of the third chunk (and `x+y+z` to the fourth chunk in my example). After the first phase, `x`, `y`, and `z` are known, and hence, `x`, `x+y`, and `x+y+z` can be calculated before entering the second phase, which is adding the right offset to each element. In my example, `x` is `19`, `y` is `12`, and `z` is `21`, which are evaluated independently in the first phase. Then, `x+y` is `31` and `x+y+z` is `52`…