# Cumulative Sum using Java 8 stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a List of Integer say list1, and I want to get another list list2 which will contain the cumulative sum up until the current index from start. How can I do this using Stream API java 8 ?

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
// initialization
list2.add(list1.get(0));
for(int i=1;i<list1.size();i++) {
// increment step
    list2.add(list2.get(i-1) + list1.get(i));
}
```

How can I change above **imperative style** code into **declarative one** ?

```
list2 should be [1, 3, 6, 10]
```

Comment: You'll notice from the answers that any solution using streams is going to be inefficient.  Streams aren't really intended for this use case.  (In general, streams aren't intended to replace all imperative code.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman I agree. But in this case I do not care about efficiency (probably should have mentioned it in the question). I wanted to write the same thing with something other than above mentioned imperative style. I could not do it myself, as I was stuck because the solution is kind of mixture of map and reduce operation

Comment: Man, the lack of tuples really hurts here.

Comment: An extremely similar question was asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230261/map-to-a-running-sum-in-java-8

Answer (score 21):

Streams are not suited for this kind of task, as there is state involved (the cumulative partial sum). Instead, you could use [`Arrays.parallelPrefix`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelPrefix(T%5B%5D,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)):

```
Integer[] arr = list1.toArray(Integer[]::new);

Arrays.parallelPrefix(arr, Integer::sum);

List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

This first copies `list1` to an array by using [`Collection.toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)), which is available since JDK 11. If you are not on Java 11 yet, you could replace the first line with the traditional `toArray` call:

```
Integer[] arr = list1.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

This solution doesn't use streams, yet it's *declarative*, because `Arrays.parallelPrefix` receives the cumulative operation as an argument (`Integer::sum` in this case).

Time complexity is `O(N)`, though there might be some non-minor constant costs involved associated with setting up the infrastructure needed for parallel processing. However, according to the docs:

> Parallel prefix computation is usually more efficient than sequential loops for large arrays

So it seems it's worth giving this approach a try.

Also, it's worth mentioning that this approach works because `Integer::sum` is an *associative operation*. This is a requirement.

Comment: Never heard of parallel prefix. thank you very much for teaching me a new concept. :). I will definitely give a try.

Comment: @run_time_error [Here's more reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) about the subject.

Comment: Don’t make your life unnecessary hard. Use `list1.toArray(new Integer[0])`. As elaborated in [this great article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/), using a zero size is even more efficient in the commonly used Hotspot JVM. That’s one of the reasons why [JDK 11’s new method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)) just does the same: “*The default implementation calls the generator function with zero and then passes the resulting array to `toArray(T[])`.*”

Comment: @run_time_error also worth reading: [How does newly introduced Arrays.parallelPrefix(…) in Java 8 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52961981/2711488)

Answer (score 6):

For every index: iterate from zero to that index, get each element, and get the sum
Box the ints to `Integer`s
Collect to a list

```
IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
    .map(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(0, i).map(list1::get).sum())
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You're adding every number together every time, rather than reusing the previous cumulative result, but streams do not lend themselves to looking at results from previous iterations.

You could write your own collector but at this point, honestly why are you even bothering with streams?

```
list1.stream()
    .collect(
        Collector.of(
            ArrayList::new,
            (a, b) -> a.add(a.isEmpty() ? b : b + a.get(a.size() - 1)),
            (a, b) -> { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
        )
    );
```

Comment: That's O(n^2) !! (as opposed to the O(n) of the OP)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Yes.

Comment: @Michael thanks for your elaborate response. I have learnt that I can write my own collector. I know this is overkill. But good to know that there are other ways.

Answer (score 6):

An `O(n)` (works only sequentially) solution would be the following, but I don't find it very elegant. I guess it is a matter of taste

```
AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();
List<Integer> collect = list1.stream()
                             .map(ai::addAndGet)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(collect); // [1, 3, 6, 10]
```

Comment: This solution only works as long as the stream is sequential. Parallelising it would break this completely.

Comment: @ben In parallel stream you couldn't have cumulative sum right?

Comment: Ruslan's answer allows for parallel streaming. The only stateful operation is over the original list itself, which we can probably assume with relative safety is read-only. Each item in the list in his solution could query over the list independently of the other stream elements.

Comment: @VenkataraghavanYanamandram with other solutions yes, but they are `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sublist`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) to sum up until the current index from start:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> list1.subList(0, i + 1).stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [`Stream.collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) for that:

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
List<Integer> list2 = list1.stream()
        .collect(ArrayList::new, (sums, number) -> {
            if (sums.isEmpty()) {
                sums.add(number);
            } else {
                sums.add(sums.get(sums.size() - 1) + number);
            }
        }, (sums1, sums2) -> {
            if (!sums1.isEmpty()) {
                int sum = sums1.get(sums1.size() - 1);
                sums2.replaceAll(num -> sum + num);
            }
            sums1.addAll(sums2);
        });
```

This solution also works for parallel streams. Use `list1.parallelStream()` or `list1.stream().parallel()` instead of `list1.stream()`.

The result in both cases is: **`[1, 3, 6, 10]`**

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is correct regardless whether the stream is parallel or not and O(n) in any case.

Comment: Here's my take at making this stateless: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70969797/402428

Answer (score 1):

The [JEP 461: Stream Gatherers](https://openjdk.org/jeps/461) Java 22 preview language feature adds built-in support for this sort of cumulative accumulation:

```java
// [1, 3, 6, 10]
List<Integer> incrementalSums = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4)
        .gather(Gatherers.scan(() -> 0, Integer::sum))
        .toList();
```

This uses the new [`Stream.gather`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)) method with the new built-in [`Gatherers.scan`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#scan(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiFunction)) gatherer to convert the initial stream to a stream of sums.

## Javadocs

[`Gatherer`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html):

> An intermediate operation that transforms a stream of input elements into a stream of output elements, optionally applying a final action when the end of the upstream is reached. […]
>
> […]
>
> There are many examples of gathering operations, including but not limited to: grouping elements into batches (windowing functions); de-duplicating consecutively similar elements; incremental accumulation functions (prefix scan); incremental reordering functions, etc. The class [`Gatherers`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html) provides implementations of common gathering operations.

[`Stream.gather`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given gatherer to the elements of this stream.

[`Gatherers.scan`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#scan(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiFunction))

> Returns a Gatherer that performs a Prefix Scan -- an incremental accumulation -- using the provided functions. Starting with an initial value obtained from the `Supplier`, each subsequent value is obtained by applying the `BiFunction` to the current value and the next input element, after which the resulting value is produced downstream.
>
> Example:
>
> ```java
> // will contain: ["1", "12", "123", "1234", "12345", "123456", "1234567", "12345678", "123456789"]
> List<String> numberStrings =
>     Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
>           .gather(
>               Gatherers.scan(() -> "", (string, number) -> string + number)
>            )
>           .toList();
> ```