# Calculating List of cumulative sums from List of integers with Java streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the following list :

```
 INPUT :: 4 5 8 -11 9 5 -7 4 6 -6 -8 -11 80 -32 -56 -15 5 -49 

 OUTPUT :: 4 9 17 6 15 20 13 17 23 17 9 -2 78 46 -10 -25 -20 -69
```

I need to calculate cumulative sum - List meaning

```
T(n) = T(n) + T(n-1) for n >0; 
and
T(0) = T(0)
```

I want to calculate that with Java stream API so that I can implement it with Spark for big data calculation. I am naive in Java Streams I have tried several expressions bt none of them is working
the equivalent stuctured code should be like :

```
int[] numbers = {4, 5, 8, -11, 9, 5, -7, 4, 6,-6, -8, -11, 80, -32, -56, -15, 5, -49};
int temp = 0;

for (int i = 0 ; i < numbers.length ; i++) {
   temp = temp + numbers[i];
   numbers[i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Stream API brings no benefit here.

Comment: What relation between spark?

Comment: @Lamanus I can use this solution with some dat atype changes to JavaRDD  in Spark

Comment: @Nikolas , I am totally new to Stream API , could you help me understand why Stream wont work ? how to implement this logic in functional way ?

Comment: This answer your question  ? [Cumulative Sum using Java 8 stream API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55265970/4207306)

Comment: @NilKulkarni Streams will work.  But there is no added benefit and in fact adds additional overhead.

Comment: @Kulkarni: The Stream API is for a processing of the collection items such as filtering, mapping, reducing operations etc. It's not suitable for iterations where are two or more items involved at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
int[] a = {4, 5, 8, -11, 9, 5, -7, 4, 6, -6, -8, -11, 80, -32, -56, -15, 5, -49};
Arrays.parallelPrefix(a, (x, y) -> x + y);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

output:

```
[4, 9, 17, 6, 15, 20, 13, 17, 23, 17, 9, -2, 78, 46, -10, -25, -20, -69]
```

Comment: thanks , Cannot do upvote though ,I dont have enough reputation

Comment: A preferred approach over streams of course. But the OP did specify a stream solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways of doing it.

The first is very inefficient as it basically uses nested loops to accumulate the values. The first `IntStream` specfies the range of values and the nested IntStream creates a variable range and sums up the values from 0 to the end of that range.

```
int[] result1 = IntStream.range(0, vals.length).map(
        i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(0, i).map(k->vals[k]).reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b))
        .toArray();
```

This one is more in line with a more conventional method.  Stream a single array of 0 and then use that to accumulate a running sum of the values.

```
int[] result2 = Stream.of(new int[] { 0 })
        .flatMapToInt(k -> IntStream.of(vals).map(v -> {
            k[0] += v;
            return k[0];
        })).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result2));
```

Both print

```
[4, 9, 17, 6, 15, 20, 13, 17, 23, 17, 9, -2, 78, 46, -10, -25, -20, -69]
[4, 9, 17, 6, 15, 20, 13, 17, 23, 17, 9, -2, 78, 46, -10, -25, -20, -69]
```

But you simply can't do any better than this.

```
for (int i = 1; i < vals.length; i++) {
      vals[i] += vals[i-1];
}
```

Bottom line is to stick with what you have.

Comment: thanks . that was bit of a eye opener for me , Streams may not bring benefit every time..

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a custom collector.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
       List<Integer> cumulatives = integers.stream().collect(CumulativeAdd.collector());
}
     private static final class CumulativeAdd {

       List<Integer> retArray= new ArrayList<>();
       int sum = 0; 

       public void accept(Integer num) {
           sum +=num;
           retArray.add(sum);
       }

       public CumulativeAdd combine(CumulativeAdd other) {
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Parallel Stream not supported");
       }

       public List<Integer> finish() {
           return retArray;
       }

       public static Collector<Integer, ?, List<Integer>> collector() {
           return Collector.of(CumulativeAdd::new, CumulativeAdd::accept, CumulativeAdd::combine, CumulativeAdd::finish);
       }

   }
```