# Is it possible to calculate values in a stream based on themselves

Tags: java, java-stream

If I have a java stream of e.g. numbers, is it possible to calculate e.g. the sums up to that number (by adding the number to the "previously" calculated sum)?

e.g. (1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 0) --> (1, 3, 6, 11, 18, 27, 27)

Comment: You can, but it can't be stateless (or without side-effects)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265797/cumulative-sum-using-java-8-stream-api

Comment: Correct answer, also taking parallel streams into account: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265797/cumulative-sum-using-java-8-stream-api#55267290

Comment: @ernest_k, here's how to implement it without side-effects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70969797/402428

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [**parallelPrefix**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) for sum of array in java stream.

```
Integer[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 0};
Arrays.parallelPrefix(arr, (x, y) -> x + y);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

You have to use [**AtomicInteger**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) for ArrayList

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 0));
        
AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();
List<Integer> sumOfList = list.stream()
                              .map(ai::addAndGet)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(sumOfList);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using Streams is to use `reducing`. This solution is *not stateless*, though.

```java
var inputList = List.of(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 0);
var result = new ArrayList<>();

var unused = inputList.stream().collect(reducing(0, (a, b) -> {
    result.add(a + b);
    return a + b;
}));

System.out.println(result); // [1, 3, 6, 11, 18, 27, 27]
```

**A few points:**

- Mutation should always be avoided while using streams. Streams are not meant to replace imperative code.
- Above solution doesn't have room for parallelism
- Streams API introduces the functional programming (what to do) paradigm in Java. It is not supposed to be mixed with imperative (how to do) code.
- The `parallelPrefix` solution in [Faeemazaz Bhanej answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70969263/8746228) should be the preferred solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof of concept building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265797/cumulative-sum-using-java-8-stream-api#55267290). It implements a fully stateless solution with O(n) time complexity that also works with parallel streams.

```
    record CumSum(Integer acc, List<Integer> sums) {
        public CumSum() {
            this(0, List.of());
        }

        public CumSum collect(Integer n) {
            return new CumSum(acc + n, concat(sums, Stream.of(acc + n)));
        }

        public CumSum combine(CumSum cumSum) {
            return new CumSum(acc + cumSum.acc, concat(sums, cumSum.sums.stream().map(n -> acc + n)));
        }

        private static List<Integer> concat(List<Integer> sums, Stream<Integer> acc) {
            return Stream.concat(sums.stream(), acc).toList();
        }
    }

    var list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
    var list2 = list1.stream().parallel()
        .reduce(new CumSum(), CumSum::collect, CumSum::combine)
        .sums;

    System.out.println(list2);
```

The output is

```
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]
```

regardless of using a parallel stream or not.

Note that due to the lack of a true immutable List in Java, `CumSum` jumps back and forth from `List` and `Stream`, which complicates this implementation unnecessarily.
Also the separate tracking in `acc` could be replaced by just looking at the last element in `sums`. For more clarity I chose not to do that.

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can use a custom collector to do that. Although the "stream" part would have nothing to do.

It would look like list.stream().collect( new CustomSequentialCollector() )