# Stream iterate not using last value

Tags: java, java-stream

## Simplified Example

I have the following code which generates the sum of a series i.e. `1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+4`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stream<Integer> inputStream = Stream.of(1,2,3,4);
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = inputStream.iterator();
    
    Stream<Integer> outputStream = Stream.iterate(
            iterator.next(),
            i -> iterator.hasNext(),
            next -> {
                return iterator.next() + next;
            }
    );

    List<Integer> outputList = outputStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(outputList);

}
```

But this prints: `[1, 3, 6]`, missing the last element.

### Working example but needs Atomic Variable

Note this seems to get the correct check I want, but is there a better solution? Looks awful:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stream<Integer> inputStream = Stream.of(1,2,3,4);
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = inputStream.iterator();

    AtomicBoolean check = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    Stream<Integer> outputStream = Stream.iterate(
        iterator.next(),
        i -> check.get(),
        next -> {
            check.set(iterator.hasNext());
            return iterator.hasNext() ? iterator.next() + next : next;
        }
    );

    List<Integer> outputList = outputStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(outputList);

}
```

## Generic Problem description

Here's a generic code illustrating the problem.

```
public static <O, I> Stream<O> iterate(O seed, Stream<I> stream, BiFunction<I,O,O> function) {
    return iterate(seed, stream.iterator(), function);
}

public static <O, I> Stream<O> iterate(O seed, Iterator<I> iterator, BiFunction<I,O,O> function) {
    AtomicBoolean hasNext = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    return Stream.iterate(
        seed,
        i -> hasNext.get(),
        next -> {
            hasNext.set(iterator.hasNext());
            return iterator.hasNext() ? function.apply(iterator.next(), next) : next;
        }
    );
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Stream<Integer> inputStream = Stream.of(2,3,4);
    BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> f = Integer::sum;
    Stream<Integer> outputStream = iterate(1, inputStream, f);
    
    List<Integer> outputList = outputStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(outputList);
    
}
```

## Problem Context

Basically, I want to do this because I am creating a function which produces a forecast of the balance of an interest bearing account.

I want to be able to take a stream of dates and then produce a stream of balances. That way you don't need to know how many elements there will be, or even the distribution of dates, which makes it a more flexible approach.

Also note that the next element of the `Stream` depends on the previous. This is why I have a `seed` which represents the first value (does not have a previous value), which would be the opening balance.

Comment: The last element does not have a successor. JavaDocs of `Stream.iterate()` say *The stream terminates as soon as the hasNext predicate returns false.*… Could be the reason for the last element to get skipped.

Comment: I've posted some ugly working code, is there anything better I could do?

Comment: Related [How does `Arrays.parallelPrefix(...)` in Java 8 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52961981/how-does-newly-introduced-arrays-parallelprefix-in-java-8-work)

Comment: Yeah so the actual problem of summing elements isn't important, it's the concept of having a stream as input, and then producing a stream as output which is a sequence of dependent calculations

Comment: @Holger I think that got messed up on edits, my first buggy code it now there which misses the last element.

Comment: Hey thanks all for the help question looks way better now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the three arguments to `Stream.iterate(…,…,…)` correspond to the three arguments to a `for(…;…;…) …` statement, where the loop’s body corresponds to the chained stream operations. But this doesn’t match an iterator loop, which looks like

```java
for(Iterator<I> iterator = …; iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    I elements = iterator.next();
    …
}
```

In other words, the right place of the `next()` call would be after the `hasNext()` check, before the remaining loop body, whereas the function passed as third argument to `Stream.iterate(…,…,…)` is evaluated after the loop body equivalent, before the `hasNext()` check.

A simple solution would be

```java
public static <O, I> Stream<O> iterate(
    O seed, Iterator<I> iterator, BiFunction<I,O,O> function) {

    return Stream.iterate(seed, Objects::nonNull,
        prev -> iterator.hasNext()? function.apply(iterator.next(), prev): null);
}
```

which effectively moves the `hasNext()` check before the `next()` call. But it requires that `null` will never occur as a normal result of the function evaluation, which should be the case for all arithmetic operations.

Otherwise, you would have to go one level deeper to implement a general-purpose stream operation:

```java
public static <O, I> Stream<O> iterate(
    O seed, Stream<I> stream, BiFunction<I,O,O> function) {

    boolean parallel = stream.isParallel();
    Spliterator<I> sp = stream.spliterator();

    return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<O>(
        sp.estimateSize() == Long.MAX_VALUE? Long.MAX_VALUE: sp.estimateSize() + 1,
        sp.characteristics() & Spliterator.SIZED | Spliterator.ORDERED) {

        O value = seed;
        final Consumer<I> c = i -> value = function.apply(i, value);
        boolean end;

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super O> action) {
            if(end) return false;
            O current = value;
            end = !sp.tryAdvance(c);
            action.accept(current);
            return true;
        }
    }, parallel).onClose(stream::close);
}
```

This is more complicated, but has no constraints of the values produced by the function and is more efficient than going through an `Iterator`. Note that this solution also cares to retain the current parallel setting and ensures that closing the stream will be delegated to the original stream, which might be important when being backed by a resource, like `Files.lines`, etc.

Comment: Can you please explain why in the constructor of `AbstractSpliterator` characteristics are truncated to `SIZED` and `ORDERED` (why not preserve all `sp.characteristics()`)?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko most characteristics depend on the result of the `function`, which this method can’t predict. It can’t know whether the `function` will produce distinct, sorted, or non-null results. All it knows, is that it will produce as many elements as the source (in fact: one more than the source) and that the order may stay significant. The `SUBSIZED` characteristic, on the other hand, will be handled by the superclass; `AbstractSpliterator` will inject it when ̀`SIZED` is present, which is the right place to do it, as the superclass will also handle the splitting.

Comment: Hey thanks heaps for explaining that with reference to the for loop, that much I can understand ( ;

Answer (score 7):

> ... but is there a better solution?

Yes, an elegant solution can be by using [`Arrays#parallelPrefix`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelPrefix(int%5B%5D,java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator)).

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        Arrays.parallelPrefix(arr, Integer::sum);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
[1, 3, 6, 10]
```

You can always convert back and forth between `Stream<Integer>` and `int[]` as per your requirement.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] arr = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).toArray();
        Arrays.parallelPrefix(arr, Integer::sum);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

        // In case , you need a Stream<Integer> again
        Stream<Integer> resultStream = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed();

        // Or want the result as a List<Integer>
        List<Integer> resultList = resultStream.toList();
        System.out.println(resultList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, looking for a stream as input to produce another stream, the actual code I have is just a simplified example of a problem I'm working on.

Comment: Most welcome.  I have added an example of how you can convert between `Stream<Integer>` and `int[]`.

Comment: Assume though that 1,2,3,4 could go to a very large value, which may or may not be read. This solution though will calculate all elements.

Answer (score 1):

> Here's a generic code illustrating the problem.
>
> ```
> public static <O, I> Stream<O> iterate(O seed, Stream<I> stream,
>                                        BiFunction<I,O,O> function) {
>     
>     return iterate(seed, stream.iterator(), function);
> }
> ```
>
> I want to be able to take a stream of dates and then produce a stream
> of balances. That way you don't need to know how many elements there
> will be, or even the distribution of dates, which makes it a more
> flexible approach.

I've written the following solution based on the assumption that it's possible to **merge** the **balances** produces in the different threads, and the function `BiFunction<I,O,O>` is [***associative***](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity), as well as a merging function `BinaryOperator<O>`, that would be responsible for combining resulting values, i.e. *balances*.

Also, the value of `seed` should meat the same requirements which are imposed on `identity` of the [`Stream.reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) operation (otherwise parallel stream would yield an incorrect result). I.e.

```
merger.apply(r, mapper.apply(seed, t)) == mapper.apply(t, r)
```

Which would not hold true if `seed` would be `1` and both `mapper` and `merger` would be defined as `Integer::sum`, but `i -> i * i` and `seed` `1` the condition would be met.

***Note** that if at least one of these requirements is not possible to fulfil, streams are not the right tool for this problem*.

Here's how it might be implemented using a custom Collector. To define a Collector we can use static method [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...)).

```
public static <R, T> Stream<R> iterate(R seed, Stream<T> stream,
                                       BiFunction<T, R, R> mapper,
                                       BinaryOperator<R> merger) {
    return stream
        .collect(sequenceCollector(seed, mapper, merger));
}

public static <R, T> Collector<T, ?, Stream<R>> sequenceCollector(R seed,
                                                                  BiFunction<T, R, R> mapper,
                                                                  BinaryOperator<R> merger) {
    return Collector.of(
        ArrayDeque::new,
        (Deque<R> deque, T next) ->
            deque.add(
                mapper.apply(next, Objects.requireNonNullElse(deque.peekLast(), seed))
            ),
        (left, right) -> {
            R last = left.getLast();
            right.forEach(next -> left.add(merger.apply(next, last)));
            return left;
        },
        Collection::stream
    );
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<Integer> input1 = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
    Stream<Integer> output1 = iterate(0, input1, Integer::sum, Integer::sum);
    
    List<Integer> outputList1 = output1.toList();
    System.out.println("Sequential: " + outputList1);
    
    Stream<Integer> input2 = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4).parallel();
    Stream<Integer> output2 = iterate(0, input2, Integer::sum, Integer::sum);
    
    List<Integer> outputList2 = output2.toList();
    System.out.println("Parallel:   " + outputList2);
}
```

*Output:*

```
Sequential: [1, 3, 6, 10]
Parallel:   [1, 3, 6, 10]
```

Comment: Haha intense code. Thanks for the answer, yeah I would have thought that if each element in the stream depends on the previous one, you can't use parallel streams? Although I don't have a requirement to make this parallel I do find it interesting  this subject. What is happening here? Is this all streams even though there are array functions here?

Comment: *"if each element in the stream depends on the previous one, you can't use parallel streams"* - There's no separate representation for the parallel and sequential streams everything that holds true for parallel stream automatically applicable to sequential streams. Stream that can run only sequentially is broken (only a small change which can be done by one of your colleagues, or even by you some time later turn the stream into a parallel one).

Comment: *"Is this all streams even though there are array functions here?"* - I'm not quite sure if I understood this question. The solution presented in the answer is stream-based. It defines a custom Collector, which an object which accumulates stream elements into a mutable container and produces the result of the stream execution (in this case it's a new stream). If by saying *"array functions"* you refer to `ArrayDeque`, then it's only a Collection used to accumulate stream elements (it's not an array, although it's backed by an array, like `ArrayList`, `HashMap`, and some other Collections).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
AtomicInteger sum = new AtomicInteger(0);
List<Integer> result = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4).map(it -> sum.addAndGet(it)).toList();
result.forEach(System.out::print);
```